# Map<int, List<int>> convert to encodable object failed

Tags: json, flutter, dart

i am trying to convert a Map<int, List int> to json, so i can save it.
Sadly i am getting this Error

```
E/flutter ( 9386): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'AppState'
```

I dont understand how i have to change my function

```
  String bookProgressToJson(Map<int, List<int>> data) =>
  json.encode(Map.from(data).map((k, v) =>
      MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, List<dynamic>.from(v.map((x) => x)))));
```

any ideas?

Comment: see if that doesn't solve `json.encode(data.toString());`

Comment: Thank you its working  fine, dont know why i tried such complicated way^^

But now there is another problem My String looks exactly like it should but now i haveve to convert it back intoMap<int, List int>  "{0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}",

Comment: The error message is saying that the encoder doesn't know how to convert an `AppState`. Does that class have a `toJson` method? Can you include the source code for that?

Answer (score 3):

JSON only encodes maps with `String` as the key. See how the thing before the colon is shown as string here: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

So, if you want to encode a `Map<int, something>` you could convert the `int` to a `String` so that you can encode it, and convert it back after decoding it, like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final data = <int, List<int>>{
    0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    1: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    2: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
  };

  final d2 = data.map<String, List<int>>(
    (k, v) => MapEntry(k.toString(), v), // convert int to String
  );

  final j = json.encode(d2);

  final d3 = json.decode(j) as Map<String, dynamic>;

  final d4 = d3.map<int, List<int>>(
    (k, v) => MapEntry(int.parse(k), v.cast<int>()), // parse String back to int
  );
  print(d4);
}
```